# Why does my html files get messed up when uploaded

Tags: html, css, ftp, hosting

So I've uploaded my html, css and js files via Pydio. But the site seems to get messed up. Can anyone tell me what happened to it and how to fix it?

Some of the google font I used shows up but some didn't. Also, the bootstrap grid doesn't show up like its supposed to be. The site also didn't scale according to screen size.

When I preview the website in Brackets, it looks perfectly fine.
Please help.

mean-design.com

Comment: I gave you a downvote, main reason for this is you didn't even provide a clickable link. You haven't told us what you've tried to figure out what went wrong, and whole bunch of other reasons. Be sure to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve even though this doesn't really apply to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot to upload some files.

Here is the list :

[image: Load files]

( click on the image to zoom in )

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that you did not upload everything or there are some absolute paths in your code. If you copy everything you uploaded to another local machine, does it work then?

You can actually see which files are missing if you open the online version of your page in your webbrowser and have a look at the developer console (press F12 in Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+I in Firefox). In the console all missing files are stated in the logged errors.

Thanks to Relisora we even have a screenshot of the error console:
[image]

Check if you uploaded all files and if so, check their path and link tags.